# Publishing diagnostics from C++?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any examples of how to publish [diagnostics messages](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostics) from C++? I can only find examples using Python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262236/publishing-diagnostics-from-c++?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its like publishing anything else.

Setup a Publisher, fill in the Message and publish it.

Here is a completely senseless example but gives you perhaps an idea:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray.h>
#include <diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticStatus.h>
#include <diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "diagnostics");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::Publisher diagnostic_pub = nh.advertise<diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticArray>("/diagnostics", 1);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticArray dia_array;
    diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus robot_status;
    robot_status.name = "Robot";
    robot_status.level = diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus::OK;
    robot_status.message = "Everything seem to be ok.";
    diagnostic_msgs::KeyValue emergency;
    emergency.key = "Emgergencystop hit";
    emergency.value = "false";
    diagnostic_msgs::KeyValue exited_normally;
    emergency.key = "Exited normally";
    emergency.value = "true";

    robot_status.values.push_back(emergency);
    robot_status.values.push_back(exited_normally);

    diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus  eth_status;
    eth_status.name = "EtherCAT Master";
    eth_status.level = diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticStatus::OK;
    eth_status.message = "Running";

    dia_array.status.push_back(robot_status);
    dia_array.status.push_back(eth_status);

    diagnostic_pub.publish(dia_array);

    ros::spinOnce();

    loop_rate.sleep();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2017-05-22**:
I'm compiling to an Arduino using `rosserial_arduino`, so `push_back()` isn't available. How do I dynamically allocate lists of type `diagnostic_msgs::DiagnosticArray::_status_type*`?

**Comment by [TheMilkman](https://answers.ros.org/users/33305/themilkman/) on 2018-08-14**:
Did you ever end up working this out? @Cerin

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you running a full ROS (and not rosserial on an Arduino) you can use the [diagnostic_updater](http://wiki.ros.org/diagnostic_updater) package to automatically fill in the diagnostics message and publish it.

The diagnostics_updater package also includes diagnosed publishers that you can use to make sure that you're publishing at your desired rate.

The diagnostics_updater package ships with some fairly good examples: http://docs.ros.org/api/diagnostic_updater/html/example_8cpp_source.html

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2